# Div Positioning Randomly Wrong in Other Browsers

Tags: css, html, position, nav

I have a 'register' div in the 'nav' of my website, and in firefox everything renders perfectly, but in other browsers such as Chrome, the positioning is completely off sometimes, but if I refresh the page, it fixes itself.

Also, if I inspect element and check/uncheck 'position:absolute', it usually goes to the correct position.

There is a lot of entangled code here, so I apologize in advance, and would appreciate any help at all!

I will post the relevant code below, but if you need to see the complete code, please go to [www.mindmote.com/nav/index.php](http://www.mindmote.com/nav/index.php)

HTML:

```
<header> 
    <img src="..." onclick="location.href='../nav/index.php'" />
</header>       
<nav>
<ul class="fancyNav">
        ...
</ul>   
  <div class="register">
      <a class="unlink" id='windowbox' style='border-radius: 10px;width:45px;' href="...">Register</a>
      <a class="unlink" id='windowbox' style='border-radius:10px;width:40px;' href="...">Log In</a>
  </div>            
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.register{
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 18px/20px;
}
a.unlink{
    color:#0f0000;
    text-decoration: none;
    clear: both;
}
a:hover.unlink{
    color:#ecf7ed;    
    text-decoration: none;
    clear:both;
}
#windowbox{
    border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    width :auto;
    height:auto;
    background: #c3912b url('../assets/img/nosp.png') repeat;
    border: 1px solid #666666; /***/
    -webkit-box-shadow:  5px 5px 10px .5px rgba(100, 100, 100, .3);        
     box-shadow:  5px 5px 10px .5px rgba(100, 100, 100, .3);
}
.fancyNav{
    position: relative;
    text-align: start;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
    list-style: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow:  5px 5px 10px .5px rgba(100, 100, 100, .3);        
    box-shadow:  5px 5px 10px .5px rgba(100, 100, 100, .3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove absolute positioning and it should be okay.